# MySQL mistake with trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, updates

if the link in the page table is updated, I want to update the links in the menubar table.
I wrote the following code but it did not.

```
CREATE TRIGGER linkdegistir AFTER UPDATE
on sayfalar
for EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE menu_icerik SET menu_icerik_link=new.sayfa_sef WHERE menu_icerik_id=new.id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `linkdegistir` AFTER UPDATE ON `sayfalar`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `menu_icerik`
SET `menu_icerik_link` = NEW.`sayfa_sef`
WHERE `menu_icerik_id` = NEW.`id`;
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Semicolon is added. Because it's a single sentence, it's possible to remove `BEGIN ... END`.